# XML preview not working because of Bottom Navigation theme

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

My android studio XML preview is not working, after searching for the cause I found out that my Bottom Navigation is the problem, by changing the app theme it breaks the ui but the preview works again. Until now I tried restarting android studio, updating the material dependency, clearing or invalidating the cache and many more things, but nothing seems to work.

[image]

I am using the google material bottom navigation.

Comment: Pls share your XML code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A possible solution to solve the Bottom Navigation issue can be :**

1. The project may have **an error** or **a warning** regarding your `.xml` code.
2. **Update** your `Google Material Dependency` and check your `Android Studio` version also.
3. `The Bottom Navigation` **theme** cannot be compatible, try to switch it to a different one.
4. Custom styles, attributes or any values can create **conflicts** with `The Bottom Navigation` **theme**.
5. **Update** the `Design Library` to the latest version.

If all these possible solutions fail, try to work on a new different ***from scratch*** project using your current code.

---

***Check this links also*** :

[Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation)

[Design Preview not Working Fixed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bX6YDhOOgPo)

[xml preview is not working in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74556604/xml-preview-is-not-working-in-android-studio)

[Different Ways to Fix “Android Studio Does not Show Layout Preview”](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/different-ways-to-fix-android-studio-does-not-show-layout-preview/)

[Update UI components with NavigationUI](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)